# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'param_distributions'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to use hyper parameter optimization in order to improve my model (gradient boosting) accuracy. Here are codes which I am trying to use:

```
grdHyperParams = {'loss' : ['deviance', 'exponential'],
                 'n_estimators': randint(10, 500),
                 'max_depth': randint(1,10)}

gridSearch_grd = GridSearchCV(estimator=grd, param_distributions=grdHyperParams, n_iter=10, scoring='roc_auc',fit_params=None, cv=None, 
verbose=2).fit(X3_train, y_train)
```

And I've got an error message:

> **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'param_distributions'

I looked for solutions and found out that version conflict might have occurred. So I checked my version and it was 0.21.3.

What should I do guys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use like this,

```
GridSearchCV(estimator=grd, param_grid=grdHyperParams, ......)
```

There is no `param_distributions` argument for `GridSearchCV`, instead use `param_grid`.

For more information, you can refer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

Comment: Can I know why this answer is not helpful, because someone downvoted this ?